# How do I split out the first 15 seconds of a video and save it to the camera roll in swift

Tags: ios, swift, video

I'm trying to grab the first 15 seconds of any video selected from the UIImagePicker and then save that to the photo library. I'm using AVFoundation to grab the first 15 seconds and then save as a new file. I think the problem is that I'm not saving it correctly but I'm not sure. The code seems to run without error at this point.

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices
import AVFoundation
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var spliceSeconds = 15.0
    var preferredPreset = AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough

    @IBOutlet weak var bnLibrary: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bnCamera: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        authVideoAccess()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func authVideoAccess() {

        let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            print("authorized")
            break
        case .denied:
            //alert
            print("denied")
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (newStatus) in
                print("status is \(newStatus)")
                if newStatus ==  PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                    /* do stuff here */
                    print("success")
                }
            }
            print("It is not determined until now")
            break
        case .restricted:
            print("permission restricted")
            break
        default:
            // show something eles
            print("default")
            break
        }


    }

    @IBAction func getVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender == bnCamera {
            self.openCamera()
        } else {
            self.openVideoLibrary()
        }
    }

    func openCamera() {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            myPickerController.delegate = self
            myPickerController.sourceType = .camera
            myPickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
            self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func openVideoLibrary() {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            myPickerController.delegate = self
            myPickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            myPickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String, kUTTypeVideo as String]
            self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    //pragmark - delegate methods
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        let vidUrl:URL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]! as! URL
        let options = [ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: true ]
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: vidUrl, options: options)


        if verifyPresetForAsset(preset: self.preferredPreset, asset: asset) {
            let assetVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first!
            let assetAudioTrack: AVAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first!
            let startTime = assetAudioTrack.timeRange.start
            let endTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(spliceSeconds, startTime.timescale)

            if assetVideoTrack.timeRange.duration.seconds > spliceSeconds {
                trimVideo(assetVideoTrack: assetVideoTrack, assetAudioTrack: assetAudioTrack, startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime )
            } else {
                //show a message
            }
        }


        //print(info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]!)
    }



    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //pragmamark - trim stuff
    func verifyPresetForAsset(preset: String, asset: AVAsset) -> Bool {
        let compatiblePresets = AVAssetExportSession.exportPresets(compatibleWith: asset)
        let filteredPresets = compatiblePresets.filter { $0 == preset }
        return filteredPresets.count > 0 || preset == AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
    }


    func getNewFilePath() -> String {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .picturesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0].absoluteString + "StorySplitter-" + UUID().uuidString + ".mp4"
    }

    func trimVideo(assetVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack, assetAudioTrack: AVAssetTrack, startTime: CMTime, endTime: CMTime) -> Void {

        var accumulatedTime = kCMTimeZero

        let durationOfCurrentSlice = CMTimeSubtract(endTime, startTime)
        let timeRangeForCurrentSlice = CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, endTime)

        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        let videoCompTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
        let audioCompTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())



        do {
            try videoCompTrack?.insertTimeRange(timeRangeForCurrentSlice, of: assetVideoTrack, at: accumulatedTime)
            try audioCompTrack?.insertTimeRange(timeRangeForCurrentSlice, of: assetAudioTrack, at: accumulatedTime)
            accumulatedTime = CMTimeAdd(accumulatedTime, durationOfCurrentSlice)
        }
        catch let compError {
            print("TrimVideo: error during composition: \(compError)")
        }

        accumulatedTime = CMTimeAdd(accumulatedTime, durationOfCurrentSlice)

        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: self.preferredPreset)
        exportSession?.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: getNewFilePath())
        exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
        exportSession?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        exportSession?.exportAsynchronously {
            print("finished saving")
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Clarification question - what's actually happening? (Besides that, I think you've asked a great question with code, what you want to happen, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
exportSession?.exportAsynchronously
```

does not save to the photo library, but just saved to the `outputURL` you specified, which is inside your app's sandbox. If you print the URL out it would be something like

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/520D8354-B1D2-465F-93C2-54F2528D1AA9/Pictures/StorySplitter-528229F9-4D4F-4E28-82C9-3B1F2FDB215B.mp4
```

Extra work to save your mp4 at above URL to the Photo Libraray.

```
exportSession?.exportAsynchronously {
     PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: newURL)
     }) { saved, error in
             // handle here
        }
}
```

Also, your `func getNewFilePath() -> String`, instead of using `FileManager.default.urls(for: .picturesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)`, you need to change to `NSTemporaryDirectory().appendingFormat("yourVideoName.mov")`

It looks like the PHPPhotoLibrary can not access the URL from the FileManager but can access in via NSTemporaryDirectory()

FYI: The above two URLs
fileManagerPath:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/520D8354-B1D2-465F-93C2-54F2528D1AA9/Pictures/StorySplitter-528229F9-4D4F-4E28-82C9-3B1F2FDB215B.mp4
```

tempPath:

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/520D8354-B1D2-465F-93C2-54F2528D1AA9/tmp/video.mov
```

which the main differneces are `files:///` and `private`, `files:///` will make the URL an absolutu URL, so in your `trimVideo` function, you have to use `URL(string: getNewFilePath())` for the export URL.

Since the same URL has to use twice and the `getNewFilePath())` is getting unique URL every time, you need to save it in a variable so that in `exportSession?.exportAsynchronously`, you can still reference the same URL for `PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: newURL)`